# Redirection to docusign portal from web application

Tags: docusignapi

Context - Currently we have built a product for managing athletic activities.There's a web app for admins and mobile app for student athletes.

Use case- Admins will be sending out documents for students to sign.

One way of doing it, is to redirect the admins to docusign login page and upon succesful authentication he gets redirected to docusign portal.

Is there a way where admins having docusign account log into our application and if when wish to send out envelopes to athletes they simply click on the docusign button and gets redirected to their individual docusign accounts without having the need to manually enter
creds again.

** The user is registered with docusign with same email id used for logging in our web application

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality to offer auto-login to DocuSign. However, you can develop an API integration with DocuSign that will allow your admins to build and send envelopes through your site. You can read more [here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/)